unwanted p2 directory in rcp application after installation
after creating an eclipse rcp application, the folder structure contains some folders like "p2" which are not required for me. Even if that is required for updates I am not interested in that, as we release new rcp application version every quarter to our customers.
Any possible way how I can stop from creating these folders.
installation folder structure:

The main intention is to remove those files created in the binary which are having some vulnerability constraints. If we extract these files we get unsigned installers. Need to get rid of those files in particular.

If you are building with [tag:tycho] you may get more responses asking in the github tycho Discussions or Issues

According to your screenshot you are talking about the p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core/cache folder only. To my knowledge, at least p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine/profileRegistry is required when using p2. What happens if you only remove the cache folder?

@howlger I get these folders generated by tycho even on a e4 RCP with no trace of p2

@howlger I haven't seen anything weird if I removed those files manually and run my workspace. Everything is just like before.

@greg-449 I don't know, but I guess that these folders are generated because Tycho makes use of p2 to build the product. Will it still start when you remove p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine/profileRegistry?

@RaviBodla Would deleting this folder be a solution for you? But better ask in the Tycho discussions to be sure as recommended by greg-449.

@howlger Seems to run fine without the entire p2 directory on macOS at least.

@greg-449 Interesting. Thanks for checking. Maybe I remembered it wrong and the p2 profile is only needed when updating.
